# Java - Online game, should the game happen in the server or the client?

Tags: java, swing, sockets

I'm implementing a multiplayer option for a chess game I made, but I'm starting from zero to do both client and server. A friend said to me to make the game happen in the server, and the client only gets the data and shows in the GUI. Does this means that I have to implement the game in the server (without GUI); and in the client project, just the GUI, actionListeners and stuff, so that, for example, when I click on a piece and then click where I want it to go, the server will "make" the move (set new position etc) and then send this information back to the client so that it can print? Is this the best approach?

By the way, my server can (*will*) host several games (each time 2 sockets connect it creates a game thread). Oh and also, after finishing the game, I want to implement a little chat in-game. Don't know if this information changes something...

Comment: Short answer is that it depends on how you want to structure your game. Either way works. What your friend is suggesting seems like the [Model-view-controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern.

Comment: While both ways work, running the game on the server has several advantages: For example it's more difficult to "hack" the protocol and add time, by asserting that your move only took a second when it actually took a minute.

Comment: @user3580294 interesting. The thing is, I don't know much about server, connections and stuff like that very well yet, so I thought that getting the game every time from the server would be hard on the internet, but on the other side making the client handle the game would need a lot more work, so any recommendation, or it really doesn't matter much?

Comment: I'd say start off doing things locally first. I'm working on an answer right now, but in essence if you do MVC right locally, moving to a server shouldn't be too hard (beyond figuring out communication protocols and such)

Comment: You don't "get the game" every time - just the state of it, or possibly even just a single move.

Comment: 'The game' is a distributed application. It happens in *both* the client and the server. The part about what happens when you encounter other players happens in the server; the part that displays your view of it happens in the client; a lot of it happens on the wire; some of it you get to choose where it goes; ...

Comment: For best performance, do both client and server. If you do it all server side, then you'll get a lag in your GUI even though you are just moving your own piece. Your moves - client, opponent's move - server.

Comment: I will try like @thedjaney said, seems like a nice solution. Thanks for all the answers. Just as a curiosity, how are MMOs made(in this matter of where the game happens)? I wanted to try doing a small online RPG, so I was wondering about that.

Comment: @WalrusNine Just a tip, read [this](http://www.reddit.com/r/gaming/comments/p1ssv/dear_internet_im_a_26_year_old_lady_whos_been/c3lup2l). Online MMOs could be significantly more work than you expect, depending on what you have in mind. Even if you aren't planning something grand it might be an interesting read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Longer answer is that you really have a lot of flexibility in how you want to do this. The "traditional" way of doing this is the model-view-controller pattern, where you separate the model (game state) from the view (what the board looks like), and a controller (your server code) handles interaction between the two.

The question is where to place each section of code.

One option is to place have the client do the heavy lifting with the server acting as a middleman between clients and communicating updates. This has the advantage that servers don't need to do as much work, but results in a client that can be easily modified for cheating.

The other option is to place most of the important code on the server and simply have each client be a "dummy" display that just shows whatever the server sends and just send the bare minimum amount of information to the server for the server to determine what was done. This is more hackproof, but places greater load on the server.

You can also do a hybrid model where the both the client and the server share the load of sanity checking, so the load on either isn't quite as severe. I think that this is a pretty good option, even though it violates the "pure" MVC pattern.

What works "best" for you might depend on the kind of load you expect on your server. For a small number of connections, "pure" MVC with "dumb" clients might work. Client makes move, server verifies that the move is valid, and if so, sends updates to both clients. If your framework starts to get overwhelmed you might want to consider putting some checking code in the client though.

None of this affects having multiple pairs of clients or a chat. You should be able to implement each of those parts separately, and if done correctly piecing the modules together shouldn't be bad.